# how to return true if the value at a selectedIndex has a space at the end

Tags: javascript

Suppose one of my options below has a space ("bb ") at the end, please see below html example.
Now even when I am selecting that value on the UI, the javascript function is returning false,
how can I resolve this ?

The below if block is not getting satisfied when I am selecting "bb "

```
    <td>
    <select multiple="multiple" id="list" style="width:100%;" size="10">
         <option value=16313>aa</option>
         <option value=15041>bb </option>
         <option value=15041>cc</option> 
     </td>

    var select =document.getElementById(list);
    for (i=0; i< select.options.length ; i++ )
    {
       if(select.options[i].selected) {
         // do something
       }
    }
```

Comment: That space shouldn't be an issue, can you make a fiddle for us?

Comment: The value would still be returning, are you trying to check for "bb" and that's failing?

Comment: no, I am not checking for "bb", I just pasted that the if block is not satisfying

Answer (score 0):

The space at the end has absolutely nothing to do with your problem.

You missed the quotes around the `list` in your `getElementById(list)`:

Try this instead :

```
select = document.getElementById('list');
```

---

Here is a working jsFiddle : http://fiddle.jshell.net/msieurtoph/umkkvo59/

Comment: M'sieur Toph, good catch. But that is not the case in my code. I am sending "list" to a function and then using there. So quotes is not an issue. Because it is working for the other values.

Comment: OK. In my fiddle, the three options are working. Does it solve your issue ? If not, please provide a fiddle with your usecase ... you did not give enough details and codes in the question ...